# call componentDidMount hook if data is in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which is dependent on redux store. 
My redux store looks like this something

```
{
  user: {
    auth: true,
    id: '5a603c58288fc745f8cada9e',
    first_name: 'john',
    email: 'xyz@abc.com',
    company_id: '5a66d8b92cd8e931680778dc',
    company_name: 'My Company',
  }
}
```

So basically when i refresh the page, store goes away and it takes sometime to fetch data and set it into store as above

I have a component which requires company_id to fetch data about that company

```
 componentDidMount(props) {
      console.log("idddddddd", this.props.company_id)
    // this.props.getCompanyData(this.props.company_id);
  }
```

using react-redux i am getting the company_id

```
CompanySetupPage.propTypes = {
  getCompanyData : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  company_id : PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    company_id : state.user.company_id
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getCompanyData})(CompanySetupPage);
```

this component, componentDidMount is being fired before store receives company_id data.
So what i want is i want componentDidMount to be called after this component gets company_id from redux store.

Comment: You don't have to change the order in which the component lifecycle functions are called, what you need is the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle hook

Comment: how would i use this?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779411/reactjs-setting-state-from-props-using-setstate-in-componentwillreceiveprops-f/43780546#43780546

Comment: Glad it helped,

Comment: consider upvoting questions and answers on SO that help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what i want is i want componentDidMount to be called after this
>   component gets company_id from redux store.

It is better to not modify when component life cycle method will be called. 
See this [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) to read more about component lifecycle method.

`componentDidMount` is triggered only once after component is mounted. company_id may or mayn't available

Better function to invoke api call in your case will be componentWillReceiveProps.

`componentWillReceiveProps()` is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. While mounting it is not invoked.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
     if (this.props.company_id !== nextProps.company_id) {
        this.props.getCompanyData(this.props.company_id);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `componentDidMount` life cycle use `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle method, like below

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
 if (this.props.company_id !== nextProps.company_id) {
    this.props.getCompanyData(this.props.company_id);
 }
}
```

For reference have a look at the documentation for this life cycle method. [Docs 
 For componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)