# State updates but does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and am unsuccessfully attempting to manage a state change. The initial state renders as expected, the state successfully changes, however the elements do not render afterwards. There are no errors in the DOM console to go off of. I've made sure to set the initial state in the constructor of the component class, and I've also tried binding the method I'm using in the constructor since I've read auto-binding is not a part of ES6. The relevant component code is as follows:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                myIDs: Array(6).fill('0')
        };
        this.getMyIDs = this.getMyIDs.bind(this);

};

componentDidMount() {
    var ids = this.getMyIDs();
    ids.then((result)=> {
        this.setState({ myIDs: result }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.myIDs)
        });
    })

};

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({
        myIDs: Array(6).fill('0')
    });
};

getMyIDs() {
    return fetch('/api/endpoint').then((response) =>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((myIDs) => {
        return myIDs.result
    })
};

render() {
    return (
        <Tweet tweetId={this.state.myIDs[0]} />
        <Tweet tweetId={this.state.myIDs[1]} />
        );
   }
}

export default MyComponent
```

UPDATE: The 'element' being updated is the 'Tweet' component from react-twitter-widgets. Its source is here:

https://github.com/andrewsuzuki/react-twitter-widgets/blob/master/src/components/Tweet.js'

```
export default class Tweet extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    tweetId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    options: PropTypes.object,
    onLoad: PropTypes.func,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    options: {},
    onLoad: () => {},
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    const changed = (name) => !isEqual(this.props[name], nextProps[name])
    return changed('tweetId') || changed('options')
  }

  ready = (tw, element, done) => {
    const { tweetId, options, onLoad } = this.props

    // Options must be cloned since Twitter Widgets modifies it directly
    tw.widgets.createTweet(tweetId, element, cloneDeep(options))
    .then(() => {
      // Widget is loaded
      done()
      onLoad()
    })
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement(AbstractWidget, { ready: this.ready })
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the `result` is an array.

Comment: What does `console.log(this.state.myIDs)` output

Comment: Array.isArray(result) returns true so I'm sure the result is an array. When I print out this.state.myIDs, it returns a list with the updated list of IDs. Thats how I can confirm that the state *did* change, it just doesn't render.

Comment: What does Element component contain?

Comment: How does you Element component look like, are you using this.props.Id in componentWillMount or componentDidMount lifecycle hooks of Element

Comment: I'm using react-twitter-widgets and using their <Tweet> component. It's source is here:

https://github.com/andrewsuzuki/react-twitter-widgets/blob/master/src/components/Tweet.js

Comment: @ark9719 It should be `<Tweet tweetId={this.state.myIDs[0]} />` insted of only `Id`

Comment: @Prakashsharma Thanks, I have that in my code I just typed it poorly in the question. It should be updated in the question now.

Comment: @ark9719 Also make sure `typeof this.state.myIDs[0] === string`.

Answer (score 2):

As in React docs:

> componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is
>   called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in
>   this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we
>   recommend using the constructor() instead.
>
> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
>   For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

you should not use ajax calls in `componentWillMount`
call ajax inside: `componentDidMount`

another thing: why do you use 
`componentWillUnmount`

the object will be removed no reason to have that call there.

Comment: That won't make any difference to OP use case. Its a practice one must follow and not a reason for the issue

Comment: `calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering`. But OP is calling `setState` asynchronously in `componentWillMount`.

Comment: I have tried both ComponentWillMount and ComponentDidMount neither with success.

Comment: please "console.log(this.state)" in your render method and lets see the output that you have for page load

Comment: This is the console output from logging this.state inside the render function,
 I've changed the unique IDs to stars:

(6) ["*******************", "*******************", "*******************", "*******************", "*******************", "*******************"]

Comment: What is your expectation in your UI now? Should it display 2  list of stars ? can you just change Tweet to <div>{ this.state.myIDs[0] }</div> and test it

Comment: When you pass a tweet ID to a <Tweet id={unique_id}> element, it fetches, renders and embeds a full tweet. I removed the IDs because I'm not trying to promote my personal twitter account.

Comment: @G_S I can render just the ID like you said. But when I put it in the tweet element, it does not render.

Comment: If you are getting the IDs that you are expecting when you add a div, there should be something fishy that <Tweet> component is doing.

Comment: @ark9719 if a simple print of the ids works well. So lets close this question and post a new one with your `Tweet` components

Answer (score 0):

The only issue that is present in your current code is that you are returning multiple Element component instances without wrapping them in an array of a `React.Fragment` or a wrapper `div`. With the latest version of react, you must write

```
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
           <Element Id={this.state.myIDs[0]} />
            <Element Id={this.state.myIDs[1]} />
        </React.Fragment>
        );
   }
}
```

Also as a practice you must have your Async calls in `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` as the React docs also suggest. You might want to read [`this answer on where write async calls in React`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392910/use-componentwillmount-or-componentdidmount-lifecycle-functions-for-async-reques/47393005#47393005) for more details

Another thing that you must remember while using prop `Id` in your Element component is that `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` lifecycle functions are only called on the initial Render and not after that, so if you are using `this.props.Id` in one of these function in Element component then you will not be able to see the update since the result of async request will only come later, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779411/reactjs-setting-state-from-props-using-setstate-in-componentwillreceiveprops-f/43780546#43780546) on how to tacke this situation

Comment: @G_S, yes you are right of course, it should throw an error for the other person, however on the contrary, I have also pointed on the other thing that could be wrong in the implementation apart from pointing out what is wrong in the provided code

Comment: I have followed the suggestions to use componentDidMount, however that has not fixed the rendering problem. I will look into the solutions you've linked. At the moment I only plan on using the prop on render and not after that.

Comment: Can you add the Element component in your question

Comment: I've updated the question with information on that component.