# React JS props are not passed to child component on parent rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this question has been asked before but the answers always seemed to hint at a problem unrelated to this scenario and I just don't see it.

I have a parent component which passes a property to a child component's state. Depending on the value of this passed property the child initially shows its view or not. Here is the way I *thought* React works:

When a parent's (or a component in general) state changes, it will be re-rendered. When it gets re-rendered, all of its children receive their props again (i.e. the constructor of the child is also invoked?). But that is apparently not how it works in this example.

#### Parent component:

```jsx
class FileListTable extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            showModal: false
        };

        this.showSelectFolderModal = this.showSelectFolderModal.bind(this);
    }

    showSelectFolderModal()
    {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    }

    render()
    {       
        console.log("Rendering table with showModal = " + this.state.showModal);
        return (
            <div>
                <table id="files-table" class="table">
                    <tr>
                <td>
                    ...
                    <span class="float-right">
                        <FileActionMenu 
                            showSelectFolderModal={ this.showSelectFolderModal } />
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
                </table>
                <SelectFolderModal 
                    show={ this.state.showModal }/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

#### `FileActionMenu` component child:

```jsx
class FileActionMenu extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                ...
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">            
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" onClick={ () => this.props.showSelectFolderModal() }>...</button>                  
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

#### `SelectFolderModal` component child:

```jsx
class SelectFolderModal extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        console.log("Received props from table");
        console.log(this.props);
        this.state = { show: this.props.show };
    }

    closeModal()
    {
        this.setState({ show: false });
        // do something post close
    }

    render()
    {
        console.log("Rendering modal with show status: " + this.state.show);

        return (
            <div id="select-folder-modal" class="modal { this.state.show ? 'show' }" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={ this.closeModal }>...</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My initial console output is this:

> Rendering table with showModal = false
>   Received props from table
>   {show: false}
>   Rendering modal with show status: false

Okay, this makes sense. But when i click on the button in `FileActionMenu` i get the following output:

> Rendering table with showModal = true
>   Rendering modal with show status: false

So the state of the parent is not passed as props to the child when the parent is updating! But I thought this is how it works, can someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779411/reactjs-setting-state-from-props-using-setstate-in-child-component/43780546#43780546

Answer (score 0):

No, your thoughts are not correct. Components' constructor are not supposed to get called every time they render/update. They get called once they are being mounted.

Back to your example, the `SelectFolderModal` should be stateless. Actually the parent maintains the app's "state". There is nothing preventing you from using "props" in `render` method:

1. In `SelectFolderModal`'s render method, use the `props` not `state` as this component is supposed to be stateless.
2. Also you need another prop for this component: `closeModal`, which parent should pass in a callback method to close the modal by setting the state.

   ```
   this.setState({ showModal: false });
   ```

Comment: But SelectFolderModal has a close button, which changes its view and also some actions have to be done. I have been struggling with the lifecycle of a modal called by an unrelated component for quite a bit. I am really not sure where to handle the states and i feel like its overkill for my project to get into Redux. Okay so the constructor is not called every time, makes sense. I guess i will have to look at some mount related methods?

Comment: @FuriousGamer The parent should maintain the state. As I updated my answer, the parent should pass in two things: 1. `show` prop and 2. a callback for `closeModal`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error in your code. You are setting the parent props(`show` props) into the child state in `constructor` which will work initially. Then each time the parent props changes, the child component receives the changed props through `shouldComponentUpdate`.

So, in your code you can access the parent props (`show`) like this:

1. Add a function similar to `showSelectFolderModal` to change the `show` value to `false`
2. Then pass the function to the child component and assign it to the button instead of `closeModal` function.

```js
class FileListTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };

    this.showSelectFolderModal = this.showSelectFolderModal.bind(this);
    this.hideSelectFolderModal = this.hideSelectFolderModal.bind(this);
  }

  showSelectFolderModal() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  hideSelectFolderModal() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <table id="files-table" class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              Main Table
              <span class="float-right">
                <FileActionMenu
                  showSelectFolderModal={this.showSelectFolderModal}
                />
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <SelectFolderModal
          show={this.state.showModal}
          hideSelectFolderModal={this.hideSelectFolderModal}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class FileActionMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <button
            class="dropdown-item"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => this.props.showSelectFolderModal()}
          >
            event button
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SelectFolderModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.show);
    return (
      <div
        id="select-folder-modal"
        class={`modal ${this.props.show ? "show" : ""}`}
        tabIndex="-1"
        role="dialog"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">...</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-secondary"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                onClick={() => this.props.hideSelectFolderModal()}
              >
                hide
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FileListTable />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the live [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqQebg?editors=0010)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

A small code change might help you in solving your problem.

Please do change your callback function as below:

```
showSelectFolderModal()
{
    this.setState({ showModal: !this.state.showModal });
}
```

In addition, send this function as a prop to SelectFolderModal component. Because you can call this function rather than calling closeModal function.

Please avoid using multiple states to perform a single action. There is no point in using a state variable in SelectFolderModal as per your code.

Comment: You should not use the state directly for setting the next state. Instead of passing `setState` an object literal you should pass in a function which receives the previous state as its first argument.

Comment: Hey @HiI'mFrogatto thanks for sharing mate. 
I really do appreciate if you edit my answer :)

Comment: Please read the documentation for [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).